# How to Create Ternary Decision Tree Layout in Google Slides/Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there way to create blank trees like the one shown below, but with an additional 2 levels, in Google Slides or Google Docs without having to do lots of manual positioning please?

[image]

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User three times. First, choose one Google Docs or Google Slides, Second provide context including what led you think that this is a built-in feature. Third, tell us if you are open to use workaround and in such case be specific about the workaround requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Select Drawing under Insert Then a drawing box will show up In the space available, add shapes and connect them with lines. To add text, click twice on the shape.
When you're done, click "Save & Close" to save your diagram.

Comment: This is what the OP don't want to do.